# Usage of @ Before Method Call

Tags: c#

Considering the Method Declaration Like this :

```
public void MethodName(string param){
       // method body
}
```

And then Calling it like this :

```
obj.@MethodName("some string");
```

What is the effect of @ before the method name ?
Does it behave like putting it before a string which contains escaped characters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is used to allow you to use reserved words as identifiers such as class names, delegates and methods. For example: `long`:

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            @long();
        }

        public static void @long ()
        {
            // Some logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Remove the `@` and it won't compile. It isn't *often* used.

*Note that the code will compile fine if you change both `long` to `long2` and remove the second `@`. So the use of `@` means you **can** call a method name that is a reserved word - but it will also work if the method name is **not** a reserved word.*

Note that the @ prefix does not form part of the identifier itself. So @myVariable is the same as myVariable.